# How can I rectify the server when httpd.conf is deleted in NAS (network-attached storage) server CentOS 5

Tags: arch-linux

The file httpd.conf is accidently deleted. Then tried from backup by putting the follwing commands

1. when using  # yum -y install httpd

   > error:   no space
2. when using # service httpd start,

   > error:   unrecognized command service

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of having to deal with underlying problems first.

- "no space" -- Disk is full (out of blocks or inodes).
- "unrecognized command service": Has nothing to do with httpd-- can't find the command "service".  This is a problem with your PATH, permissions (you need root privileges!), or something more essential is broken or missing.